# How do I block an attack in Plain Sight?

Tags: plain-sight

I saw that the secondary mouse button is mapped to **block** and that there are power ups that let you recover faster after being blocked.

However, pressing the secondary mouse button does nothing; is blocking a purchasable upgrade? Can it be done only in specific times?

How do I block in Plain Sight?

Comment: for the records, the other way to block an attack is to charge your enemy at the same time as he charges you. Swords will meet, and both attacks will be repelled (doesn't work if he has the the flaming sword, though, as for blocking)

Comment: I think there's even an achievement for that too @gno (great game, a little difficult to maneuver but very entertaining)

Comment: ["The Best Defense is a Good Offense"](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/PlainSight/achievements), indeed. (Game is good, but I got tired of the "best player becomes stronger", increasing the gap between good (or lucky) players and the poor lemmings who can't land a kill.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must purchase it in order to use it, the option being found under Shield in the upgrade menu. Upgrading will increase the length of time you can wield it.

Comment: Actually, its recharge speed is a separate upgrade.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right. Editing to correct that. I was tired when I answered this. :P

Comment: Thanks, apparently when you buy the shield power up you also get the ability to block, it wasn't clear to me at first.